# How to automate integration tests of FQL queries against different sets of test data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, testing, facebook-fql, integration-testing

Are there any frameworks or tools or other methods for automating integration tests of FQL queries?

By integration tests I mean I want to run the queries against the production facebook graph API.

I can use the Graph API Explorer, or just hit endpoints, to test a query manually against my own profile data - but I want to test a query against different test users with different volumes, types and patterns of data than exist in my personal profile, and verify that the result is what I expect in each different case.

I.E. the standard automated testing pattern..

1. Set up test data (presumably on a test user)
2. Run query against test data
3. Verify expectations on results

..and repeat for as many test cases as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no widely known or used framework to achieve this.

Thus, you'll need to create a test user. Populate it with what it is you want. Authenticate that test user. and then run the FQL on it. Thats your only option to run the tests you are looking for.

Comment: Normally I'd be skeptical of a flat no response, but having googled on this without finding anything and observing the fact you're working at facebook, I'll take your word for it :)

Comment: I could be wrong. But I've worked extensively with the API and never seen one. ;)